# Does the Saver in TensorFlow have a cross-platform file format?

Tags: cross-platform, tensorflow

Suppose I execute the following on machine A after some calculations for some `tf.Session` `sess` and some `tf.train.Saver` `saver`, assuming I have some `tf.Graph` `G` with some variables `V`:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Define G, V, initialize for sess, then run some computation
    saver.save(sess, '/A/somefolder/somefile')
```

This creates `somefile`, `somefile.meta`, and updates `checkpoints` in `somefolder`.

Next, suppose on machine B I copy the entire contents of `somefolder` and run the following:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Define G and V the same way. No initialization or run here.
    saver.restore(sess, '/B/somefolder/somefile')
```

For both machines A and B, will the variables have the same state at the end of the code blocks? Is this guaranteed to work across all platforms? What about different versions of Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saver uses a simple file format [based on LevelDB](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/lib/io/table_format.txt) to store a key-value table that maps variable names (as strings) to [`SavedTensorSlice` protocol buffers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/util/saved_tensor_slice.proto). The format is intended to work across all platforms, although it has mostly been tested on little-endian (i.e. x86-based) architectures. The same file should work across different versions of Linux, and between Linux and Mac OS X. If it doesn't, please raise an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)!